# Nginx PHP FPM installation issue on Virtualmin

Tags: nginx, php, webmin

I have a linode and I used LEMP script to install nginx. Then I used Virtualmin for managing my virtual servers. When I use phpinfo(), my version was 5.3.2 and server api is CGI/FastCGI. I updated my ubuntu repositories and had a new php 5.4 which includes php5-fpm by default.

Now phpinfo() says I have php 5.4.11 but still shows CGI/FastCGI as Server API. I've tried to start the php5-fcm service, it's working.

My problem is, I couldn't switch Server API to PHP-FPM. I need to use Virtualmin+Nginx+PHP-FPM together.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm` ?